# Validate geojson object

Tags: php, json, geometry, geolocation, geojson

I have my geojson object, and i want to test whether the object is in correct format or not. How can i validate or check my geojson object.
(i am working on php platform)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using projections EPSG:4326 or EPSG:900913, you can use this example to test your geojson data: http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/vector-formats.html

Answer (score 2):

I created [geojsonlint.com](http://geojsonlint.com/) a few weeks back to help with this. You can paste your geojson data at the site above or POST your GeoJSON to http://geojsonlint.com/validate to get a response that indicates (in)valid GeoJSON.

Comment: it works like a charm except large ones like this 
http://vmgeoserver.vd.dk/geoserver/VD/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=VD:TEMA_MARIUS_EQA&cql_filter=EQUIPMENTTYPE='Tavlestander'&outputFormat=JSON&srsName=EPSG:4326

Comment: and it would be perfect if it could validate geoJSON by a link